# auto left and right padding blocks top and bottom padding

Tags: css, padding

I am a beginner to CSS and I see a strange problem.

I want to add top and bottom padding to my footer. I can of course use the padding-top and padding-bottom separately but I would like to use the padding property.

If I use padding: 45px auto for my footer, the top and bottom padding do not apply.
Whereas if padding: 45px 0 is used for the footer, the top and bottom padding works fine.

What's wrong? I have already checked the padding MDN page and it does not even have mention of auto :(

Please help.

```css
footer {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px auto;
  padding: 45px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2024 Footer Text</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Center the elements with "display: flex; justify-content:center;" as footer CSS.

Comment: I want to add top and bottom padding to my footer. I can of course use the padding-top and padding-bottom separately but I would like to use the padding property.

Comment: Padding can't have auto as value.

Comment: Thanks! It never occurred to me that auto might be an invalid value! I just assumed that because margin can be set to auto, so padding can be too! *blush*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding can't have auto as value, that's invalid.

If you just want to set top and bottom, you need to use `padding-top/-bottom`.

If you want to center your elements left/right:

```
footer{
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-block`

```css
footer {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding-block: 45px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2024 Footer Text</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```